# How do I pass an argument in C / Bash Scripting?

Tags: c, bash

Hi have an easy C program that does the following when I run it with ./a.out

Please enter your name:

What I want to do, is I want to automatically pass the name without having to wait for the prompt. I tried ./a.out Sam, but it would still prompt for a name. I'm trying to write a bash script that would do that.

Any help would be appreciated. Note: I don't want to modify the C source. All I want to do is be able to pass the first argument without having to wait for the prompt.

Comment: In the future, if you want your program to take an argument from the command line, use the `argc/argv` parameters in `int main( int argc, char **argv )`.  `argc` is the total number of arguments on the command line (including the command that invokes the program), `argv[0]` is the command you used to invoke the program, and `argv[1]` through `argv[N-1]` are the additional arguments you passed on the command line (represented as text strings).

Answer (score 4):

The program reads from `stdin`. You can pipe to stdin:

```
echo "Sam" | ./a.out
```